# Trying to get relationships using SugarCRM API

Tags: php, api, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to pull an individual billing record and some specific fields using SugarCRM's legacy REST API.  I am working on SuiteCRM and they use the same legacy REST API calls.  I have another foreach similar to this one that does work just fine.  The only problem is that this one will only return the requested info and not the relationship I am calling in link_name_to_fields_array.

Thanks in advance.  Please let me know if more information is needed.

I followed this example [here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/SOAP/PHP/Retrieving_a_List_of_Records_With_Related_Info/)

My code is as follows

```
foreach ( $uids as $uid ) {
             //retrieve records -----------------------------------     
                $get_entries_parameters = array(

                     //session id
                     'session' => $session,

                     //The name of the module from which to retrieve records
                     'module_name' => 'fs_payments',


                     //An array of SugarBean IDs
                     'ids' => array(
                        $uid 
                     ),

                    'query' => "",
                    'order_by' => "",
                    'offset' => "0",

                    'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'fs_billing_fs_payments_1',
                            'value' => array(
                                'first_name',
                                'qb_studentid'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),



                );
```

Just did an API call to get all links and I did confirm the link name is what it should be and there is no reason it should be returning an empty array.

```
Linked Fields for fs_payments

fs_billing_fs_payments_1
[name] -> 'fs_billing_fs_payments_1'
[type] -> 'link'
[relationship] -> 'fs_billing_fs_payments_1'
[module] -> 'fs_billing'
[bean_name] -> 'fs_billing'
```

Does anyone have a better example than [this](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/05_Method_Calls/get_entries/)(shown below as well) as it is not very helpful in my opinion as true relationships/links in the CRM have names such as 'fs_billing_fs_payments_1' and seem to not work as the example shows.

```
$get_entries_parameters = array(
 //session id
 'session' => $session_id,
 //The name of the module from which to retrieve records
 'module_name' => 'Accounts',
 //An array of record IDs
 'ids' => array(
     '14b0c0ca-3ea2-0ee8-f3be-50aa57c11ee7',
 ),
 //The list of fields to be returned in the results
 'select_fields' => array(
    'name',
    'billing_address_state',
    'billing_address_country'
 ),
 //A list of link names and the fields to be returned for each link name
 'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
      array(
           'name' => 'email_addresses',
           'value' => array(
                'email_address',
                'opt_out',
                'primary_address'
           ),
      ),
 ),
//Flag the record as a recently viewed item
'track_view' => true,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the set_entry and bean relationship built into suiteCRM to pull 
the qb_studentid and accoutingclass and set them as hidden fields using a separate function so that they would show in the array when pulled using get entry in the actual api call to get the large array.
This file is called using a logic hook to ensure that all qb_student IDs are pulled 
after a payment is synced. If you require a bit more detail on this please feel free to let me know.  I struggled with this issue for some time and still have no answer from anyone not here nor in the sugarcrm or suitecrm community forums.  This is more of a workaround if anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong link name in `link_name_to_fields_array`.

Your link field name is `fs_billing_fs_payments_1` but you are passing `fs_billing_fs_payments_1_c`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response.  I did check on that and forgot that I pasted the older version of the code I was running I have all the exact same that I have here except the correct field name and this still did not work.  Any ideas?